# Wildcard replace in Notepad++ with line breaks at unknown positions

Tags: notepad++

I have an XML file in which I need to replace a certain, reoccuring text. However, line breaks and carriage returns can appear in the text anywhere.

The text is always like this:

@RELEASED{XXX}

where XXX is the text that changes, can be pretty much anything, and can include line breaks and carriage returns anywhere within (as far as I have seen it is always the two together). It can also happen that there is no line break and carriage return in the text at all.

I have tried to do the following:

\@RELEASED{.+}

This does replace the relevant text if there are no line breaks and carriage returns in it.

I have then tried to replace \r\n with a string that does not appear anywhere, and then do the same thing again:

\@RELEASED{.+}

However, in this case this replaces a single, large chunk of the file, instead of every appearance (maybe it goes from the very first appearance of this text to the very last, and replaces everything between these two).

Search mode is set to Regular expression, Wrap around is unticked. I have tried to play around with these settings to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the solution the way its meant to be, but I have a very good work-around.

First replace all line-breaks with a unique text, such AS #####LINEBREAK##### to make all line-breaks be text. Then use your first regex to alter the text, then replace #####LINEBREAK##### back to \r\n.

Comment: I have tried that and for some reason this replaces a single, large chunk of the file, instead of every appearance. \r\n was replaced with %%% which does not appear anywhere in the file, and after that:

\@RELEASED{.+}

replaced almost the entire file, instead of the 150 or so appearances of the target text. It might be that it skipped all of the closing brackets except for the last one.

Comment: you do know { and } are also regex chars, right? So you need to escape those too.

Answer (score 0):

Found that all of the occurences had a closing `</tp>` after them, so I did the following:

Find what:

\@R.*?<

Replace with:

<

Wrap around, Regular expression, matches newline ticked.

It seems it did the trick. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if your problem is resolved.